# meaning of ``partial converse''

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, propositional-calculus

In the definition of a commutative ring $(R,+,\times)$, one of the postulates given is that of uniqueness, i.e. that 
$$
a=a', b=b'\implies a+b=a'+b', ab=a' b'.$$
The text states that for the system $\mathbb{Z}$ of all integers, an additional property holds, namely $c \ne 0, ac=bc \implies a=b$.  This property is mentioned to be a ''partial converse'' of the above postulate.  I was wondering what exactly the phrase ''partial converse'' means in general.

It seems to me that the converse itself (i.e. the full converse) need not be true, but some weaker form of it (that uses additional hypotheses) might be true, and so we call this a partial converse. For example, in the above postulate, if the ring is the set of integers, the converse $a+b=a'+b', ab=a'b' \implies a=a', b=b'$ need not be true, but $ab=a'b'$ along with $a =a' \ne 0$ do imply $b=b'$.  In general, if $p, q \implies r$ is a statement, its converse $r \implies p,q$ need not be true, but $r$ along with another additional hypothesis, say $s$, might imply $p,q$, for example a partial converse could be $r, s \implies p$ or $r,s \implies p,q$. Am I correct?

I read online that a partial converse of $a, b \implies c$ is $c, a \implies b$, which is along the lines of what I had thought.  Does the additional assumption that is added need to necessarily be one of the hypothesis of the original statement, as in the example just given, or can it be a new statement $s$ like in the previous paragraph? I think it can be a new statement, for I saw somewhere that Sylow's theorem is a ''sharp partial converse'' to Lagrange's theorem.  Lagrange's theorem states that if there exists a subgroup of $G$ of order $k$, then $k | o(G)$. The converse need not be true, but $k |o(G)$ and the additional assumption that $k$ equals $p^m$ for some prime $p$ and $p^{m+1}$ does not divide $o(G)$ do imply that there exists a subgroup of order $k$. I'm not sure why this partial converse was also called ``sharp''.  Any other examples of ''partial converse'' and ''sharp partial converse'' would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think your first line is really a postulate, because your implication says nothing at all.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: The first line is given as the second of the eight postulates in [Birkhoff and MacLane, Surveys of Modern Algebra] for the definition of a commutative ring.  I agree it seems to say nothing.  It looks like the remaining seven postulates are equivalent to the other definition of a commutative ring: $(R,+)$ is a commutative group, $(R,\times)$ satisfies closure, associativity and identity, and the distributive laws hold. I'm not sure whether the second postulate can be deduced from this other definition.

Comment: To me, that line is a postulate indeed, but it is an axiom (my preferred word) of *equality*, and has nothing to do with algebra. I think this notion of equality being a more fundamental notion may be a relatively modern point of view, however. Mixing in equality axioms with other axioms seems to be a hallmark of older texts.

Comment: It just says that $+,\cdot$ are well-defined, i.e. in fact binary operations.

Comment: Yes Martin, I think you're right about the postulate.  But I should mention again that the question is about the phrase ``partial converse''.

Answer (score 3):

Generally if $P\implies Q$ is an axiom or a theorem, the converse $Q\implies P$ might be false, but the adjoining of a condition $R$ might make $(Q\land R)\implies P$ true. When $(Q\land R)$ can be considered to be a small amendment of $Q$ we might call $(Q\land R)\implies P$ a partial converse of $P\implies Q.$ E.g. if $P$ is $a=b$ and $Q$ is $ac=bc$ and $R$ is $c\ne 0.$

Answer (score 1):

My answer above is **incorrect**.  Website [themathpage.com](https://themathpage.com/) has this, expressed with the
symbolism above:  For the proposition
$ p \land q \rightarrow r $,
the *partial converse* is
$ r \land p \rightarrow q$.
I apologize for the error, but this latest *is* accurate.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).